# Codeigniter AutoComplete Stop working when i put the code under login conditions

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

The Code Runs Fine when i run the code without login Conditions, When i put code under login condition it gets stop. if a login into application even that time code is not under login conditions but the search gets stop until i restart my computer

My Controller

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class autocomplete extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
{
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];


}
else
{
redirect('login', 'refresh');
}
}
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('view_demo');
}

    public function start()
{
    $json = [];

    $this->load->database();


    if(!empty($this->input->get("q"))){

$this->db->like('name', $this->input->get("q"));

$query = $this->db->select('drugs_id as id,name as text')

->limit(10)

->get("drugs");

$json = $query->result();

}


    echo json_encode($json);
}
}
```

Here is My View

```
 <div style="width:520px;margin:0px auto;margin-top:30px;height:500px;">
 <h2>Select Box with Search Option Jquery Select2.js</h2>
 <select class="itemName form-control" style="width:500px" name="itemName">
 </select>
 </div>
```

Here is Script

```
$('.itemName').select2({
    placeholder: '--- Select Item ---',
    ajax: {
      url: 'http://localhost/dcms/autocomplete/start',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please Help Me i am waiting

Comment: i have found the solution. First i remove the line cache: True
and then  removed ::1 in web link i put localhost and permanently set in config.config base url as http://localhost/project_name